# Prevent winforms application resizing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winforms application.my problem is ,i have a mdi child form called Frmaddpackage which has a size of 892 * 339.but if any i open this form while which is full screen,then i open my form Frmaddpackage,it will show as full screen.

how can i remove that,so that Frmaddpackage  is always of fixed size.i have set the formborder style as fixed single.

1.This is actual screen size.[image]

But if i open any of forms,and then i open my form the size is increased as.
[image]

Comment: Whats about your parent window? Is the formborder style as fixed single ?

Comment: Do you want your child window form opened externally or inside the mainform itself ?

Comment: all the forms are mdi child forms.what i want is child forms open inside the mdi parent.with size always fixed.mdi parent window formborder style is sizable

Comment: `which has a size of 892 * 339` - Don't do this. People with larger screen resolutions will find your application as a tiny little box in the upper left corner or their screens. Even with winforms, you can do better than that. Otherwise use WPF, which is resolution independent by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the forms WindowState property once the form has been shown which might solve the issue.

```
Frmaddpackage.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Could you also try to set the WindowState to Minimized and then to Normal

Answer (score 0):

You can set maximum form size equal to size.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
   this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
   this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size("Set the Current Size");\
   this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size("Set the Current Size");
```

so that form wont get maximized ... i mean set current size as Maximum size

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on InitializeComponents() or Form.Load()

```
this.MinimumSize = this.Size; //Minimum size is current size
this.MaximumSize = this.Size; //Maximum size is current size so window can't be smaller than current size and can't be bigger!
```

Optionally you can change FormBorderStyle to fixed, and if you want to disable possibility of Maximalization, use:

```
this.MaximalizeBox = false; //Disabling resizing may cause bugs with maximalization of window.
```

Sorry for my bad English, but code should work well (I use it in my applications)

Comment: If you want, to auto resize of controlls use Anchor in window desinger.